# Uso TempData ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pelo que andei a pesquisar ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc)), consigo guardar uma lista de dados numa TempData criada numa função, para usar em outra função no meu Controller.

Ora bem, estou a tentar fazer isso mesmo, só que não estou a conseguir:

Model:

```
...
namespace ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels
{
    public class Localidades
    {
        public string Familia { get; set; }
        public string Subfamilia { get; set; }
        public string Registo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocalidadesFormViewModel
    {
        public Localidades Localidades { get; private set; }

        public LocalidadesFormViewModel(Localidades localidades)
        {
            Localidades = localidades;
        }
    }
}
```

Função onde crio a TempData:

```
public ActionResult AtribuirOrdemServ()
{
    ...
    var newListaLocalidades = new List<ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.Localidades>();
    foreach (var item in localidades)
    {
       var newItemLocalidade = new ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.Localidades();
       newItemLocalidade.Familia = item.ToString().Split(',')[0].Split('{')[1].Split('=')[1].Split(' ')[1];
       newItemLocalidade.Subfamilia = item.ToString().Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1].Split(' ')[1];
       newItemLocalidade.Registo = item.ToString().Split(',')[2].Split('=')[1].Split(' ')[1];
       newItemLocalidade.Descricao = item.ToString().Split(',')[3].Split('}')[0].Split('=')[1].Split('"')[0];
       newListaLocalidades.Add(newItemLocalidade);
   }

   TempData["ListaLocalidades"] = newListaLocalidades.ToList();

   return View("IndexAtribuirOrdemServ");
}
```

Depois estou a tentar aceder a outra função, via JavaScript, e queria buscar esta TempData:

```
$("#divResultFiltroAtribuirOrdemServ").load("FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ"
, function () {
...
});
```

E a função `FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ`:

```
public ActionResult FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ(){
    ...
    var teste = (Localidades)TempData["ListaLocalidades"];
}
```

Onde obtenho a `TempData["ListaLocalidades"]` sempre `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo cast pra um objeto Localidades, mas na verdade deveria fazer casting de um Lista de Localidades:

```
(List<Localidades>)TempData["ListaLocalidades"];
```

Ao invés de usar o método `View`, use `RedirectToAction`, assim ele vai passar pelo `ActionResult` que você criou e quer trabalhar com os dados.

```
return RedirectToAction("IndexAtribuirOrdemServ");
```

A forma que você fez ele passa direto pra View sem entrar na ActionResult, você pode também trabalhar com os dados na View:

```
@foreach (var item in (List<ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.Localidades>)TempData["ListaLocalidades"])
{
    @Html.Raw(item.Descricao)
}
```

Comment: nisso tens razão e foi burrice minha que não reparei, a situação é que a `TempData["ListaLocalidades"]` está a null, logo não me resolve o problema

Comment: Eu testei aqui funcionou normalmente, você quer passar essa TempData pro Controller IndexAtribuirOrdemServ?

Comment: Não, quero passar `AtribuirOrdemServ()` para a View(), e depois na `FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ()` aceder os dados. Esta última função chamo a partir do JavaScript

Comment: Editei a resposta, vê se atende o que você quer.

Comment: Já vi, a questão é que uma função não tem nada a haver com outra. Uma carrega uma página (AtribuirOrdemServ()), e a outra (FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ()) carrega uma partial com resultados de filtros aplicados pelo utilizador. Ao fazer RedirectToAction perco o sentido da funcionalidade

Comment: Se eu falar que eu acabei de testar criei as views, adicionei sua função e na ActionResult a List<Localidades> veio populada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19857/discussion-between-cesarmiguel-and-laerte).

Comment: acabei por carregar a lista novamente na função `FiltroAtribuirOrdemServ()` e tentei optimizar ao máximo umas consultas que tinha para não haver perdas de tempo. Vou validar a tua resposta porque parece ser a correcta